# Is there a way to integrate TFS Source Control into Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, tfs, version-control

Recently our R&D team started using **TFS**. This resulted in migration from **SVN** to **TFS Source Control**. I have managed to find two Android Studio plugins for TFS support.

The first one is [Team Foundation Git plugin](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/androidstudio), this plugin sadly supports **only TFS Git**.

Then there is [Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=) which seems like the right candidate but is still **very unstable**, and **crashes** in my instance (I am unable to do any check-in or updates).

Is there any other way to work with **TFS Source Control** within the **Android Studio**?

Comment: Which features in TFVC do you want to use?

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the standard source control features which are available for others versioning systems. Adding files and searching for changes within Visual Studio is a huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a UserVoice for adding TFVC to this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981) at website below, you can vote it. Microsoft Product Team will evaluate it carefully:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6785457-tfs-plugin-for-android-studio,

The existing plugin only enables working with Git repositories (clone, import, push and create pull requests), on VSTS and TFS 2015.